# Using Postgres LAG with a TEMP table

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns, lag

In a mobile app that I am currently developing I keep track, serverside, of how many visitors enter/leave the area of visibility of one or more BLE beacons.  The app communicates the unique (string) ID of the beacon along with the day (as a difference from 01/04/2021) and 5 minute time slot at which the event happened.  All of this ends up - via an intermediate Redis clearing house - in the following PGSQL table

```
CREATE TABLE iobeacons (
 "beacon" character varying(24) NOT NULL,
 "tag" integer NOT NULL,
 "slot" smallint NOT NULL,
 "hits" smallint NOT NULL,
 "action" smallint NOT NULL
) WITH (oids = false);

INSERT INTO "iobeacons" ("beacon", "tag", "slot", 
"hits", "action") VALUES
('abc', 1,  1,  5,  -1),
('abc', 1,  2,  4,  -1),
('abc', 1,  1,  15, 1),
('abc', 1,  3,  2,  -1),
('abc', 1,  4,  2,  -1),
('abc', 1,  5,  2,  -1);
```

With this done I have the following table

```
Beacon   Tag   Slot  Hits   Action
----------------------------------
  abc     1      1      5     -1
  abc     1      2      4     -1
  abc     1      1     15      1
  abc     1      3      2     -1
  abc     1      4      2     -1
  abc     1      5      2     -1
```

What I can infer from this table is the following

- 15 visitors entered *beacon field* `abc` in the first five minute time slot on Day 1
- 4 of those left that *beacon field* during the next five minute interval
- 2 visitors lingered for each of the periods: 10 - 15 minutes, 15 - 20 minutes and > 20 minutes

What I need to do is be able to run SQL queries to extract such information efficiently. Take for instance the question

> Find the number of visitors who entered beacon field *abc* during the 1st 5 minute slot on Day 1 and then left after a stay duration of between 10 & 15 minutes.

SQL is not quite my forte so all I have been able to come up with thus far is this

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE hitset(sumhits) AS (select sum(hits) from iobeacons where beacon = 'abc' and tag = 1 and (slot < 2) and (action = 1) UNION select sum(hits) from iobeacons where beacon = 'abc' and tag = 1 and (slot = 2 or slot = 3) and action = -1);

select sumhits,lag(sumhits,1) over (order by sumhits) from hitset;
```

Where I am attempting to do the following

- Create a temporary table with a column called `sumhits`
- Insert into that table the sum of all entering "hits" for beacon field *abc* on Day 1 and time slot 1 AND
- the sum of all exiting "hits" for the same beacon field on Day 1 and during the time slots 2 or 3

All good so far.  I get the following table

```
 sumhits
    6
   15
```

Here I enter unchartered (for me) territory with `LAG`.  What I have attempted to do is to get the difference between the `sumhits` columns of two rows of the temp table.  The result I get is this

```
sumhits    lag
   6       NULL
  15        6
```

My, incomplete, understanding of `LAG` suggested that in the second row, above, I should get 15 (Row 2) - 6 (Row 1) = 9.  Why is this not the result?

---

This is an rephrased version of a question I had asked yesterday - quite extensively rephrased, and with my own efforts thus far, for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am slightlty surprised not to have got an answer here.  I am leaving the question with my own answer.  `LAG` simply gets a column from a prior row.  Any arithmetic against the corresponding column in the current row has to be performed in the select.  So in this instance that last SQL SELECT should read

```
select sumhits - lag(sumhits,1) over (order by sumhits) from hitset;
```

You will find an excellent reference on performing such calculations using `LAG` [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/calculating-differences-between-rows-in-sql/).